# Excel/VBA loop only executes on the first file

Tags: excel, vba, data-processing

I'm have about 100 `.xls` files under one folder and I have a Macro script to loop through each one to do some data processing. The objective is to split each workbook into three with name `N1`, `N2`, `N3` respectively. So far my `SplitData` Macro worked fine but I have issue with extracted workbooks.

I want to merge newly extracted three workbooks to already existed ones instead of getting alerts like "File N1 already exists." every time. I changed `Application.DisplayAlerts = false` because of my previous question's suggested answer but now I got a new error:

After the alert is disabled, my first two extracted workbook keeps updating same result from the first workbook that I started extraction while the third one trapped in a loop, adding same result from the starting workbook. I assume there's something wrong with my loop but cannot find it, can anyone help me check please?

Thanks a lot!

This is my code to loop through folder:

```
Sub OpenFiles()
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xls")

    Do While xFile <> ""
        Call SplitData
    Loop
End Sub
```

This is SplitData Macro:

```
Sub SplitData()
 ' 1. Fill every cells in merged columns for future steps
            Dim cell As Range, joinedCells As Range

            For Each cell In Range("E4:I60")
                If cell.MergeCells Then
                    Set joinedCells = cell.MergeArea
                    cell.MergeCells = False
                    joinedCells.Value = cell.Value
                End If
            Next


            ' 2. Split original sheet into three based on one col value 
            ' loop through selected column to check if has different values
            Const NameCol = "B"
            Const HeaderRow = 3
            Const FirstRow = 4
            Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet
            Dim TrgSheet As Worksheet
            Dim SrcRow As Long
            Dim LastRow As Long
            Dim TrgRow As Long
            Dim Student As String
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Set SrcSheet = ActiveSheet
            LastRow = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcSheet.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row
            For SrcRow = FirstRow To LastRow
                Student = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcRow, NameCol).Value
                Set TrgSheet = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set TrgSheet = Worksheets(Student)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If TrgSheet Is Nothing Then
                    Set TrgSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
                    TrgSheet.Name = Student
                    SrcSheet.Rows(HeaderRow).Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Rows(HeaderRow)
                End If
            TrgRow = TrgSheet.Cells(TrgSheet.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            SrcSheet.Rows(SrcRow).Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Rows(TrgRow)
            Next SrcRow
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True


            ' 3. Extract three new worksheets into three workbooks 
            Dim Pointer As Long

            Set MainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Range("E4").Value = MainWorkBook.Sheets.Count

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False   'enhance the performance
            For Pointer = 2 To MainWorkBook.Sheets.Count
                Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
                MainWorkBook.Sheets(Pointer).Copy After:=NewWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                NewWorkbook.Sheets(1).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                With NewWorkbook
                    .SaveAs Filename:="D:\***\Inventory\" & MainWorkBook.Sheets(Pointer).Name & ".xls"
                End With
                NewWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
            Next Pointer

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have to open and close the file.

```
Sub OpenFiles()
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xls")

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Do While xFile <> ""
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xFile) '<~~ open file
        Call SplitData
        Wb.Close (0) '<~~ close file
        xFile = Dir '<~~ re dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Actually I have tried the method you provided but the loop just stopped at the first file and then excel closed.

Comment: Hey a little update, I removed `Wb.Close(o)` from your code and splitting started working, even though things got a bit messy(I have to not close the first file because it's the only file I inserted macros). Now the only problem is extracted workbooks not merging. They only added by name `N`, `N 1`, `N 2` ...

Comment: @Danni, Your splitData () code should clarify your relationship with the workbook in openfile ().

Comment: I really don't know how to do this. Can you please specify a little? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `xFile = Dir` in your loop to cycle through the files.

```
...
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xls")

    Do While xFile <> ""
        Call SplitData
        xFile = Dir
    Loop
...
```

It's unclear on how xFile gets passed to SplitData. Shouldn't SplitData have an argument that receives xFile?

Comment: Hi thanks for your info. I just tried your method but still same result. Btw no need to pass `xFile` to `SplitData` right? cuz each time `xfFile` just calls the `SplitData` macro. Do you think it's the reason the loop stuck at the first file?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that passes xFile to SplitFile. There isn't even anything that opens the workbook located at xStrPath &  "\"  & xFile.

Comment: But my goal is to process all workbooks without opening each one. Cuz every time I added open file argument the excel just stopped working while executing macro because I only intered Macros for the first workbook and it cannot work after closing it.